# Can powdered formula spoil on very hot days?

Tags: infant, formula

During the last few days the temperature where we live has been going up. During the day it is around 40 degrees Centigrade. Will the tub of powdered formula I have been using for my four month old go bad at that temperature?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE, Meenakshi! A similar question has already been asked (see [Is milk powder left in a hot car going to go bad?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14502/is-milk-powder-left-in-a-hot-car-going-to-go-bad)) -- however, you're asking about consistently storing formula at a high temperature and so this seems fairly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at one [manufacturer's recommendation for storage of their formula products](https://www.similac.ca/en/frequently-asked-questions) to get this answer.

> For unopened cans of Similac® infant formulas, most desirable  storage
>   temperatures are between 13°C [55°F] and 24°C [75°F], but between 0°C
>   [32°F] and 35°C [95°F] is also acceptable. **Storage at extreme
>   temperatures compromises the quality of the product.** For that
>   reason, you should not use infant formulas stored for long periods at
>   extreme temperatures.

Your brand may be different, but powdered infant formulas all follow the same general recipe. Unless the manufacturer explicitly says so, there is a risk that high temperatures can affect the formula and so you should find somewhere to store it that is at least consistently below 35°C, and preferably below 24°C.

To make things more complicated, however:

> Do not store cans of powder infant formula in the refrigerator. 
>   Instead, store them covered, in a cool, dry place.

If you can find a cool, dry place (perhaps a kitchen cupboard that doesn't get frequently opened during the day), that is the best solution until the heat wave is over.

Comment: What is interesting is that this also means storing it in the car during freezing weather is also not recommended. I wouldn't have thought about that with powdered formula.